# Dimple.js bar chart transitions including removed bars

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

When transitioning to new data that has less or different bars in a dimple bar chart the bars that are removed are pushed on top of each other to the left of the chart and stay for the whole transition time.

Here is an example of code that recreates the effect:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
var data = [
    { Animal: "Cats", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
    { Animal: "Dogs", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
    { Animal: "Mice", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
    { Animal: "Rat", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
    { Animal: "Cow", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) }
];
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Animal");
x.addOrderRule(["Cats", "Dogs", "Mice"]);
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
myChart.draw();

d3.select("#btn").on("click", function() {
   myChart.data = [
     { Animal: "Cats", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
     { Animal: "Dogs", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
     { Animal: "Mice", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) }
   ];
   myChart.draw(1000);
});
```

If you click on the button in the example you will see the effect.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nf57j/25/

(dimple adapted from John Kiernander's answer here: [Update dimple.js chart when select a new option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905429/update-dimple-js-chart-when-select-a-new-option))

Is there a way to keep the removed bars out of the transition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've rewritten all the transition code for Dimple v2.0 which I'll be releasing on Monday.  I've just tried this example in version 2 and it looks a lot better.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just tried it with 2.0.0 and it looks like the removed bars are still rendered outside of the graph and transitioned away. Is there a way to just have them removed without being part of the transition?

Comment: damn, when I replied to you, that wasn't happening.  I think it relates to a change I made to fix the axis transitions.  How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nf57j/27/

Comment: Thank you, I ended up here from the same example as well. I wish the author would update it to dimple 2 on jsfiddle for stupid copynpasters like me.