# Dimple overlaid the new plot after selecting from a dropdown menu: Solution?

Tags: drop-down-menu, updates, scatter-plot, dimple.js

I would like to update an interactive scatter plot in [dimple](http://dimplejs.org) using a dropdown menu, however I am having some issues with this task. An example of my code is below:

```
<select name="xAX" id="xAX">
        <option value ="Distance">Distance</option>
        <option value ="Redshift">Redshift</option>
    </select>

        <div id ="chartContainer">

        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var dropdown = d3.select("#xAX")
            var xAX2 = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

               d3.csv("tabula.csv", function(data) {
                      dataset = data.map(function(data) { return [
                                                                  data["Object"],
                                                                  +data["Redshift"],
                                                                  +data["Distance"],
                                                                  +data["Scale"],
                                                                  data["Type"],
                                                                  +data["IRAS12um"] ]; });

                      },


                 var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 900, 900);

                var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
                      myChart.setBounds(100, 180, 730, 550)
                      myChart.showGridlines = true;
                      var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", ["Redshift","Distance"]);
                                x.addOrderRule(["Redshift","Distance"]);
                      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Redshift");
                      myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "IRAS12um");
                      myChart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.bubble);
                      myChart.addLegend(70, 10, 610, 80, "right");
                      myChart.draw();

                      d3.select("#xAX").on("change", change)
                        function change() {
                        this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
                        }
                            myChart.draw(1000);
            });
```

The "tabula.csv" table has X headers with Y elements per header. I would like that the x- and/or y-axis would have any possible option of the X header.

I have tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905429/update-dimple-js-chart-when-select-a-new-option) but it did not really make what I would like. Any help on the code or other example would be very helpful.

----- UPDATE ----

I updated the code and I can change the plot from a dropdown menu. However, the new graph is plotted on top of the old one. How the old plot can be removed?

```
    <h2>X-Axis</h>
    <select id="xAX" name="xAX">
        <option value ="Distance" selected>Distance</option>
        <option value ="Redshift">Redshift</option>
    </select>

    <div id="chartContainer">
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 900, 900);

        var dropdown = d3.select("#xAX")
        var change = function() {
        var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

               d3.csv("tabula.csv", function(data) {

                var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
                      myChart.setBounds(100, 180, 730, 550)
                      var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", source);
                      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Redshift");
                      myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "IRAS12um");
                      myChart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.bubble);
                      myChart.addLegend(70, 10, 610, 80, "right");
                      myChart.draw();

                      });

        }

        dropdown.on("change", change);
        change();
        </script>
```

Comment: ---- SOLVED ----
To solve this issue, the following line 

svg.selectAll("*").remove();

need to be added after var change = function(data) {

Comment: Thanks, solved my initial problem perfectly! Any chance you have animated this so the chart simply cycles through all the dropdown options?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<h2>X-Axis</h>
    <select id="xAX" name="xAX">
        <option value ="Distance" selected>Distance</option>
        <option value ="Redshift">Redshift</option>
    </select>

    <div id="chartContainer">
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 900, 900);

        var dropdown = d3.select("#xAX")
        var xAxis;
        var myChart;
        var draw = function() {
               var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

               d3.csv("tabula.csv", function(data) {

                      myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
                      myChart.setBounds(100, 180, 730, 550)
                      xAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", source);
                      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Redshift");
                      myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "IRAS12um");
                      myChart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.bubble);
                      myChart.addLegend(70, 10, 610, 80, "right");
                      myChart.draw();

                      });

        }

        var change = function() {
            var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;
            xAxis.categoryFields = source;
            myChart.draw();

        };

        dropdown.on("change", change);
        draw();
        </script>
```

This will make it so you don't have to remove the original svg objects, if you add a delay in myChart.draw(800, false); in the change function, it will animate the change.